# Django TypeError while trying to list objects in html

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to make manually create form for a model but when I try to call object.all() method it gives me TypeError error in return.

```
def addPatient(request):

con = Intensivecare_Form.objects.all()
context = {'items': con, 'title': 'Items'}
if request.method == 'POST':
    patient = Patient(name=request.POST.get("fname"), data=request.POST.get(
        "lname"), Intensivecare_Form=request.POST.get("cform"))
    try:
        patient.full_clean()
        patient.save()
    except ValidationError as e:
        # Do something based on the errors contained in e.message_dict.
        # Display them to a user, or handle them programmatically.
        return HttpResponse("Your form is wrong, try again")


return render(request, context, 'AddPatient.html')
```

I couldn't do to return model data for html.

```
TypeError at /api/v1/localmngr/addPatient

join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'dict'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/localmngr/addPatient
Django Version:     3.2.4
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'dict'

Exception Location:     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/genericpath.py, line 152, in _check_arg_types
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.9.6
```

Models

```
class Intensivecare_Form (models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    hospitals_id = models.ForeignKey(Hospital, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    formname = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    data = models.JSONField()
    unites_id = models.ForeignKey(Unite, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Patient (models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    data = models.JSONField()
    intensivecare_forms_data_id = models.OneToOneField(
        Intensivecare_Forms_Data, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Intensivecare_form = models.ManyToManyField(Intensivecare_Form)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Id = {self.id}, name = {self.name}'
```

I checked the error the html file does not affect the error. I think only effecting thing is object.all() from intensive care form. I do not know how can I get datas from model into html in a proper way.

Comment: What is Intensivecare_Form? Is it a Model or a Form class?

Comment: Please include the complete error. Check this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough

Comment: Please share the complete traceback of the error.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. Intensivecare is a model which has relation with the patient model.

Comment: `render(request, context, 'AddPatient.html')` you have the arguments in the _wrong_ order here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shows the signature of the `render` function:

> ```py
> render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)
> ```

You can see `template_name` is the **second** argument, while `context` is the **third** argument, hence the below line is incorrect:

```py
return render(request, context, 'AddPatient.html')
```

Instead it needs to be:

```py
return render(request, 'AddPatient.html', context)
```

Comment: I didn't know that order is important in render. I should read documentation more carefully then. Thank you!

Comment: @nogabemist well unless you pass them as keyword arguments, the ordering of arguments is important in any python function.

Comment: Can I ask you how can I use two context?

Comment: @nogabemist Just merge the dictionaries see: [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression (taking union of dictionaries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-taking-union-of-dictiona)